# How to retrieve the values of a split and place them into separate vars

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, split

so i am working on a project with node.js, express, mongo, socket.io. I was able to retrieve the geolocation coordinates and place them into a hidden input field and then pass it along to the server to be able to save it into the db. The problem is that it will save empty. So my solution is that i created a json object ( `var point = { type: "Point", coordinates: [ req.body.coordinates ] };`). I console.logged it and saw that is returns my coordinates as i string. So the next step is to explode the string after the comma and then place the value into separate vars.

I was able to split the coordinates after the comma but how do i to get the separate values into their own var.

This is my code:

```
var point = { type: "Point", coordinates: [ req.body.coordinates ] };   
//console.log(point);

var convert = req.body.coordinates;
console.log("Logging req.body.coordinates");
console.log(point);

var split = convert.split(",");
console.log("Logging split");
console.log(split);
```

the output of console.log split is the following

> Logging split
>   [ '4.3986154', '51.222003900000004' ]

What i want do is put 4.3986154 into var x and 51.222003900000004 into var y

Any help help is welcome.

Comment: You already have them in different places, in an array? You'd get the first one with `split[0]`, and the second one with `split[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just store array items in separate variables:

```
var x = split[0];
var y = split[1];
```

BTW, I would recommend you that storing them in an object should be even better:

```
var coordinateArray = req.body.coordinates.split(",");

var point = { type: "Point", coordinates: { x: coordinateArray[0], y: coordinateArray[1] };
```

And you would access them using dot syntax: `point.coordinates.x` or `point.coordinates.y`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in environments that support ECMAScript 6:

```
let [x, y] = convert.split(",");
```